# Separating Multiple Observations R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, reshape

I have two columns in a data frame, Worker_ID and Location_ID. Each row contains the location a specific worker was at. These columns could have multiple Worker_ID's that are the same, based on different Location_ID's or the same. This data is from multiple months, so it is possible that there are multiple of the same rows of Worker and Location ID's.

An example is below:

```
Worker_ID      Location_ID
124893842      43432585855
148934855      38495485433
243243535      53535958383
```

I would like to display this data so that I can see each Worker_ID and all of the corresponding locations in columns beside it so I can later visualize this data. I tried reshape but I can't seem to get it to work right. Would anyone have any idea of how I can go about this?

Comment: adding example of desired output will help you get answers faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have limited number of unique location_id values for each worker_id, you can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data_frame(
  worker_id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
  location_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4)
  )
df %>%
  group_by(worker_id) %>%
  mutate(location_number = row_number()) %>%
  spread(location_number, location_id, sep = '_')

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   worker_id [3]
  worker_id location_number_1 location_number_2
*     <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>
1         1                 1                 2
2         2                 3                 4
3         3                 1                 4
```

I used some made up data since your data does not seem representative of your problem and the desired output. This solution is going to work, but produces as many columns as the maximum number of unique locations a single worker is at.

Answer (score 0):

This solution creates a list of vectors containing locations for each unique Worker_ID.

```
l <- lapply(unique(d$Worker_ID), function(x) d[d$Worker_ID==x, 'Location_ID'])
names(l) <- unique(d$Worker_ID)
print(l)

# $`124893842`
# [1] 43432585855
# 
# $`148934855`
# [1] 38495485433 53535958383 53535958384 53535958385
# 
# $`243243535`
# [1] 53535958383
```

(I added a few entries to expand the dataset and illustrate the point)